# XMLHttpRequest not working in google chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension, xmlhttprequest

I have been breaking my head over this for quite some time now.I am trying to send an xmlhttprequest to google and log the corresponding data into my console.
My code:

```
sendRequest();
function sendRequest()
 {
              var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.open(
    "GET",
    "http://www.google.com",
    true);

req.send(null);
console.log(req.responseText);
 }
```

I have added permissions in my manifest.json. However when i debug it prints nothing. Just an empty line. What am i doing wrong here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your error is in fact that you treat async XMLHttpRequest function as sync. There's no response from Google when you call console.log. Your code should look like this:

```
sendRequest();

function sendRequest() {
    var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    req.open("GET", "http://www.google.com", true);
    req.addEventListener("load", function(e) {
        console.log(req.responseText);
    }, false)

    req.send(null);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

The answer by Dmitri Sorin will work just fine. Here's a little bit more universal version:

```js
sendRequest('http://www.google.com/', function (response) {
    alert('My request returned this: ' + response);
}); 

function sendRequest(url, callback) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
            callback(xhr.responseText);
        }
    };
    xhr.open("GET", url, true);
    xhr.send();
}
```

Comment: Because you are trying to do a cross-domain request. This shows up in the console: "XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://www.google.lv/. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://fiddle.jshell.net' is therefore not allowed access. "

Comment: Would it be possible to include this header in html file itself?

Comment: No. It's part of the HTTP protocol. It has nothing to do with the HTML document. See this page for more details: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/HTTP/Access_control_CORS

Answer (score -1):

```
sendRequest();

function sendRequest() {
    var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    req.open("GET", "http://www.google.com", false );// set the third argument to false
    req.send(null);
    console.log(req.responseText);
}
```